# Expectation of the sample median for symmetric distributions

Tags: median, sample, unbiased-estimator

Is the sample median an unbiased estimator of the population mean when the distribution is symmetric?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think so yes, so long as

1. The population mean is defined, and
2. The sample is composed of iid draws.

For a symmetric distribution, the median is an unbiased estimate of the population median and the mean equals the median.

However, what it won't be, in general, is the most efficient or minimum variance unbiased estimator (the exception being the [Laplace distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution) for which median is the best estimator of the mean).

Comment: (+1) I've reworded things slightly to try to avoid a possible misinterpretation. We can get away with somewhat less in terms of the sampling scheme: exchangeability is enough.

Comment: The additional caveat left unstated is that there is an implicit assumption here that the population median is *unique*.

Comment: Is that a caveat though?  The sample median is always an unbiased estimate of one of the population medians, and if that one happens to be the mean, then this still holds.  It seems to me that if the sample median for even samples is the mean of the two either side, then this should work?

Comment: The sample median is *not* always unbiased for the population median. Just take $n = 1$ and your favorite asymmetric distribution to get a counterexample, though, of course, the inequality is true much more generally.

Comment: But for a symmetric distribution, it is surely unbiased?

Comment: Yes, if the median is unique. It is unbiased for the point of symmetry of the distribution. In the case the median is not unique, we can't speak of *the* median and, even so, the more typical way of getting around this is via the pseudoinverse, which will not result in "the" median being defined at the point of symmetry in the nonunique case.

Comment: But the point here is not about the population median, but the sample median. Surely, by construction, the sample median is unbiased for the point of symmetry, even if the pop median is not unique? Or have I missed something?

Comment: Sorry, I fear some dangling participles in my previous comment may have caused confusion. Yes, the sample median is unbiased for the point of symmetry for a symmetric distribution, even when the population median is not unique. Calling it unbiased for "the" median is a stretch, though. *But*, the main point of my very first comment was that, the original phrasing in the answer might give the impression that the sample median is *always* unbiased for distribution's median, regardless of whether the distribution is symmetric or not. That was the main point I was originally trying to address. :)